# URLError: [WinError 10060] | When trying to install wordnet through Anaconda Jupyter (python)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, nltk, corpus

I am getting this error -

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

When I try to download wordnet by using this code on Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda (python) -

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

What should I do?

I tried turning off firewall and then running the code, but it did not work, got the same error again.